# Python REST API localhost CORS issues

Tags: javascript, python, reactjs, api

I'm working on an assignment which needs a **python backend** and **react.js frontend**. While both of those parts are working fine individually, I am having some problems dealing with the interaction between the two.
I am using a **flask** based python REST API for the backend. When the API is hosted on *pythonanywhere* it works with the frontend perfectly. The problem is that the implementation should be able to be run locally and **offline**. I tried running the API on *localhost:5000* and the front end is running via npm *localhost:3000*. When I try to access the API this way I get the error: *Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at http://localhost:5000/api/list/all. (Reason: CORS header ‘Access-Control-Allow-Origin’ does not match ‘True’).*
I had a similar problem for the hosted version, but using Simple Requests fixed that. The same approach is not working here.
I would appreciate any advice you have.
Thanks in advance.

Edit: Found a solution. I used flasks jsonify method. It turns out the problem was that the data was text and this caused the CORS problem

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python Flask Cors Issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28461001/python-flask-cors-issue)

Comment: This is actually a common problem. You need to set headers to allow cross origin requests (browsers block them by default) [Read more here to see how to enable this on different platforms](https://enable-cors.org/)