# Python Flask routes not found when using AJAX to POST

Tags: python, ajax, flask

I am attempting to route my Flask routes and see the correct return from Flask (the returns indicated in my code below). When I direct my page to `mypage.com/`, I do see the output, but it seems to be returning the xxamp apache index page in my console when I am expecting to see "hello world".

here is my directory listing:

```
/localhost
    /my_dir
        /js
        /templates
        app.py
```

Here is my AJAX call to `/`:

js:

```
$(function(){
$('button').click(function(){
    var user = "user";
    $.ajax({
        url: '/',
        data: user,
        type: 'POST',
        success: function(response){
            console.log(response);
        },
        error: function(error){
            console.log(error);
        }
    });
});
});
```

And here is my Flask:

app.py:

```
from flask import Flask, request, send_file, render_template, json
from ftplib import FTP                                                                      

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def hello_world():
return 'hello world!'

if __name__ == "__main__":
app.run()
```

There seems to be a disconnect here. I believe my Apache is running on 80 where Flask is listening on 5000. So my javascript AJAX call is actually making a call to port 80 instead of 5000, hence, why I think I am seeing a different return than expected. Do I have to specify the port in my AJAX call, or should I have flask listen on port 80?

Comment: Did you call app.run() in your app.py? Run the Flask app like: app.run(host='0.0.0.0', debug=True, threaded=True, port=<some-port-number>)

Comment: @RogerHuang Yes, sorry, i do have that in my code. I just updated the code.

Comment: Use $ curl localhost:<some-port-number> to see if your flask app receives the http request, there should be some useful logs in the console.

Comment: @RogerHuang OH do i have to manually run the flask before i run the ajax request?

Comment: Yes. You have to run the server locally (and maybe deploy to other place later).Use commands like: $ python app.py and you should be able to see: * Running on http://127.0.0.1:5000/ for more info: http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/1.0/quickstart/

Comment: You mentioned that you're receiving response from Apache server(at default port number 80). Just make sure the Flask app/server is running at the port you specified (test it with curl command), and check if AJAX is using the correct API path(server, port, and route).

Comment: @RogerHuang So I tried running it first, and then trigger the AJAX from the js, but still no luck. I still only able to get back from `/`. All the other routes are not found. Also, i see that when i run it it shows ` Running on http://127.0.0.1:5000/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/174204/discussion-between-roger-huang-and-kkmoslehpour).

Comment: @RogerHuang It seems to be working `curl -X GET http://127.0.0.1:5000/index -d'test'` but my AJAX call seems to not be hitting that port (still getting 404 not found on button click in the console). This is running on a webserver do i need some special config for the AJAX call to make the call the port 5000?

Comment: @kkmoslehpour You can either server the web page at port 5000 (using Flask, and then access the page using '127.0.0.1:5000') or change the AJAX url to '127.0.0.1:5000/index' and enable CORS. Check out: https://stackoverflow.com/q/28461001/1825443

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to add POST with acceptable method

```
@app.route('/index', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def index():
    return render_template('index.html')
```

Comment: `@app.route('/index')` and do `curl -X POST http://127.0.0.15000/index -d'test'` I've gotta 405 method not allowed response

Comment: Typo? $ curl -X POST http://127.0.0.1:5000/index -d'test' ?

Comment: `127.0.0.1:5000` :)

Comment: It seems to be working `curl -X GET http://127.0.0.1:5000/index -d'test'` but my AJAX call seems to not be hitting that port. This is running on a webserver do i need some special config for the AJAX call to make the call the port 5000?

Comment: I don't think so. try to add variable user /<user> instead of / only. Use GET and concat your user on Ajax call '/myuser'