# No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header on POST (Flask API)

Tags: python, post, vue.js, flask, fetch

I am working on my first API and so far I have been able to google for help, but I am stuck on this one:

My POST requests work fine on Postman, but when I try to use a form in my HTML to make a POST request, I get the following error:

> Access to fetch at 'http://127.0.0.1:5000/api/v1/units' from origin 'http://localhost:63342' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.
>
> index.html:1 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Failed to fetch

The method in my Flask app:

```
@marshal_with(unit_fields)
def post(self):
    args = self.reqparse.parse_args()
    unit = models.Unit.create(**args)
    return unit, 201, {"Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",
                       "Access-Control-Allow-Methods": "POST",
                       "Access-Control-Allow-Headers": "Content-Type",
                       "Location": url_for("resources.units.unit", id=unit.id)}
```

The fetch call in Vue.js app:

```
addUnit: function() {
       fetch("http://127.0.0.1:5000/api/v1/units", {
           method: "POST",
           headers: {
               "Content-Type": "application/json"
           },
           body: JSON.stringify({
               name: document.querySelector("#unitName").value,
               faction: document.querySelector("#unitFaction").value
           })
       })
   }
```

Thank you for any advice how to get past it :)

Comment: You might want to look at this post, they suggest to use flask-cors. https://stackoverflow.com/q/28461001/6511985

Answer (score 4):

Amazing, thanks, Stephan! All it needed was:

```
from flask_cors import CORS
```

and

```
CORS(app, support_credentials=True)
```

in app.py!

Comment: Isn't it `supports_credentials`? https://flask-cors.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#flask_cors.CORS