# Error: XMLHttpRequest error. with flutter and flask get mothed

Tags: python, flutter, dart, http, flask

I'm new to Dealing with flutter. I want to build connections between python and flutter with flask but I have XMLHttpRequest error how to solve it.
the code:

[image]

[image]

```
onChanged: (value) {
       url = 'http://10.0.2.2:5000/api?the=' +value.toString();
},
```

Comment: Seems to be CORS issue as you are using it on web. you need to fix it from api side. This may help you for this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28461001/python-flask-cors-issue