# Why does React to Flask call fail with CORS despite flask_cors being included

Tags: python, reactjs, api, flask

I need to read data from flask into react.
React:

```
const data = {
        name: 'John',
        email: 'john@example.com'
    };

    axios.post('http://127.0.0.1:5000/api/data', data)
        .then(response => {
            console.log(response);
        })
        .catch(error => {
            console.log(error);
        });
```

Flask:

```
from flask import Flask, request, jsonify
from flask_cors import CORS

app = Flask(__name__)
CORS(app, origins='http://localhost:3000')

@app.route('/api/data', methods=['POST'])
def process_data():
    data = request.get_json()
    # обработка данных
    response_data = {'message': 'Sucsess'}
    return jsonify(response_data), 200


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

And i take in browser an error: Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://127.0.0.1:5000/api/data' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
ShortPage.jsx:24 AxiosError {message: 'Network Error', name: 'AxiosError', code: 'ERR_NETWORK', config: {…}, request: XMLHttpRequest, …}

How can i fix this?

Comment: Weird. Does it work with origins=“*”? Try origins=[“http://localhost:3000”], ie array and double quotes.

Comment: also doesn't work

Comment: It seems is not working at all. To confirm try plain “CORS(app)”

Comment: yes, the same troubles

Comment:  just clutching at straws here. You did install it like this “ $ pip install -U flask-cors”? Maybe try the first answer here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28461001/python-flask-cors-issue/43019954#43019954

Comment: Of course......

Comment: No matter the language, CORS is always the biggest problem. Will react and flask run on the same origin when deployed? If so disable checking on your browser in dev - https://simplelocalize.io/blog/posts/what-is-cors/#

Comment: Maybe methods=['POST', 'OPTIONS']

Comment: Thank you, it works with ['POST', 'OPTIONS']  and @cross_origin(origin='*')

Comment: Cool. I bet you nearly gave up. I’m going to do some research as to why OPTIONS was not open by default and turn my comment into an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you are limiting the path /api/data to the http method POST

@app.route('/api/data', methods=['POST'])

CORS requires the client to make an `OPTIONS` 'pre-flight' call on that path to find out which origins are allowed (and other stuff like headers). Because your code only permits `POST` the `OPTIONS` call is declined and the CORS mechanism fails.

The fix is to add the `OPTIONS` to the list of permitted methods on the route.

```
@app.route('/api/data', methods=['POST', 'OPTIONS'])
```